# why a Chinese character takes one char (2 bytes) but 3 bytes?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have the following program to test how Java handle Chinese characters:

```
String s3 = "世界您好";
char[] chs = s3.toCharArray();
byte[] bs = s3.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] bs2 = new String(chs).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println("encoding=" + Charset.defaultCharset().name() + ", " + s3 + " char[].length=" + chs.length
                + ", byte[].length=" + bs.length + ", byte[]2.length=" + bs2.length);
```

The print out is this:

***encoding=UTF-8, 世界您好 char[].length=4, byte[].length=12, byte[]2.length=12***

The result are these:

1. one Chinese character takes one `char`, which is 2 bytes in Java, if `char[]` is used to hold the Chinese characters;
2. one Chinese character takes 3 `byte`s if `byte[]` is used to hold the Chinese characters;

My questions are if 2 bytes are enough, why we use 3 bytes? if 2 bytes is not enough, why we use 2 bytes?

**EDIT:**

My JVM's default encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: You're using different encoding. You're not just taking the bytes of those chars.

Comment: UTF-8 encoding can use up to 4 bytes per character. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of text encodings.

Comment: Why do you think that 2 bytes are enough?  [U+1F6B2](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%9A%B2) takes 2 `char`, which is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

A Java char type stores 16 bits of data in a two-byte object, using every bit to store the data. UTF-8 doesn't do this. For Chinese characters, UTF-8 only uses 6 bits of each byte to store the data. The other two bits contain control information. (It varies depending on the character. For ASCII characters, UTF-8 uses 7 bits.) It's a complicated encoding mechanism, but it allows UTF-8 to store characters up to 32-bits long. This has the advantage of taking only one byte per character for 7-bit (ASCII) characters, making it backward compatible with ASCII. But it needs 3 bytes to store 16-bits of data. You can learn how it works by looking it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: it is nicely described in the part of the "Encoding" section of the UTF-8 wikipedia article including examples for special characters or languages, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding

Comment: I should add that UTF-8 was designed to also be compatible with C and C++. In these languages, a byte value of zero meant the end of a String. UTF-8 is designed to never produce a byte of zero for one byte of a multi-byte character.