# Isn't a chinese character 4bytes?

Tags: php, byte

When I interpret this in php:

```
$html = htmlentities("漢");
    var_dump($html);
```

the output says, string(3) "漢", so 3 bytes?

Comment: what's your actual q?

Comment: +treyBake what is q?

Comment: +treyBake just a test

Comment: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: q = question :)

Comment: Cizzl It seems to be 3 bytes, thanks

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to use a lot of @MiguelMunoz answer on a similar question here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709916/why-a-chinese-character-takes-one-char-2-bytes-but-3-bytes)) :

> For Chinese characters, UTF-8 only uses 6 bits of each byte to store the data.
>   The other two bits contain control information. (It varies depending
>   on the character. For ASCII characters, UTF-8 uses 7 bits.) It's a
>   complicated encoding mechanism, but it allows UTF-8 to store
>   characters up to 32-bits long. This has the advantage of taking only
>   one byte per character for 7-bit (ASCII) characters, making it
>   backward compatible with ASCII. But it needs 3 bytes to store 16-bits
>   of data. You can learn how it works by looking it up on Wikipedia.

So : it is indeed 3 bytes.

Comment: I'm still quite new here. As the question wasn't exactly the same, I didn't thought it was the correct option.
I can see now that asking a question where a duplicate may exist is considered okay but answering said question is quite the crime ;)

Comment: @HadrienK. the question doesn't have to match for it to be a dupe :) it's more about the answers given too :)